# How to get value of single input field and sending with each products to database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have page, where i add one or many products (this part is working) and its adding  products including (Product Name, Serial number, Qty) to database. As also you see in screenshots [image: Screeshots] i have single input field **Customer Name** which i want get value of Customer Name input feild and sending with each products to database.

Example when data inserted into database:

### Customer Name | Product Name | Serial number | Qty

Stackoverflow                A                                   1234                        1

Stackoverflow                B                                   4567                        2

But, right now look like this in my database when its inserting data :

### Customer Name | Product Name | Serial number | Qty

null                                 A                                   1234                        1

null                                 B                                   4567                        2

To be honest i dont know how can i sending value of Customer Name input field with each products when its trying insert data into database. Can anyone please help me or point me into the right direction! Thanks in advance :)

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProcessCreateRMA(CreateRMAVM vm)
{
    using (var namespace = new namespace())
    {
        if (vm.vares == null)
        {
            vm.vares = new List<CreateRMAVM.vare>();
        }

        foreach (var item in vm.vares)
        {
            var rmainsert = new RMA_History
            {
                //CustomerName = item.CustomerName,
                ProductName = item.ProductName,
                Serialnumber = item.Serialnumber,
                Qty = item.Qty,

            };

            db.RMA_History.Add(rmainsert);
        }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Add input field 
        var i = 0;
        $("#add").click(function (e) {
            i++;
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#tbhold").append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><div><input type="text" name="vares[' + i + '].ProductName" id=' + i + ' /></div></td><td><div><input type="text" name="vares[' + i + '].SerialNumber" id=' + i + '/></div></td><td><div style="padding:0" class="col-md-12"><input id="Qty" name="vares[' + i + '].Qty"/></div></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" id="' + i + '" name="remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button></td></tr>');
        });

        //Remove input field 
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#row" + button_id + '').remove();
        });

    //Save to db by click
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessCreateRMA", "User")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ($('#add_rma').serialize()),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function () {
            console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
    });

 });
</script>
```

View:

```
<label>Customer Name</label>
<input type="text" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName">

<form name="add_rma" id="add_rma">
    <table id='tbhold' class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name </th>
                <th>Serial number</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="vares[0].ProductName" id="ProductName" />
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="vares[0].Serialnumber" id="Serialnumber" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input name="vares[0].Qty" id="Qty"/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add more</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateRMAVM
{
   public List<vare> vares { get; set; }

    public class vare
    {

        public vare()
        {

        }

        public vare(/*string CustomerName*/ string ProductName, string SerialNumber, string Qty)
        {
        }

        //public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Qty { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code to work. If you are using a datagrid, I might recommend you use one of the numerous ones out there and not try to rebuild it yourself. jqGrid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is one that's popular

1. Leave the CompanyName **inside** your form
2. Update your model as such. I've include the Customer in CreateRMAVM and in vare

   ```
   public class CreateRMAVM
   {
   public List<vare> vares { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }

   public class vare
   {

   public vare()
   {

   }

   public vare(/*string CustomerName*/ string ProductName, string SerialNumber, string Qty)
   {
   }

   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
   public string Qty { get; set; }
   }
    }
   ```

   3. Update your controller as such. CustomerName will come populated in CreateRMAVM, and then there's a line of code to copy into the vare lists

   `[HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Create(CreateRMAVM vm)
   {
   try
   {
   if (vm.CustomerName != null && vm.vares != null)
   {
   vm.vares.Select(c => { c.CustomerName = vm.CustomerName; return c; 
   }).ToList();
   }`

Comment: I tried that before ,if i move customer name input inside form tag it will serialize input just for first row and than when i add more row it will be no more customer input field and than i should add customer name input into my Javascript (i add more row or inputs dynamically via javaScript) so it will add customer input field everytime i add more input fields and its not wat i looking for . the thing i looking for just  one customer name input field and than send value of customer name field every time i add more products.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName">
```

is not within your form definition. Move this into the form